# LINQ to DataTable, finding duplicate rows

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

Using the following DataTable:

```
    Dim d As New DataTable()
    d.Columns.Add("Product", GetType(System.String))
    d.Columns.Add("Value", GetType(System.Double))

    d.Rows.Add(New Object() {"OAP1", 100.0})
    d.Rows.Add(New Object() {"EPP4", 100})
    d.Rows.Add(New Object() {"OAP1", 150.25})
    d.Rows.Add(New Object() {"OAPIN", 200.0})
```

I'm trying to use LINQ to identify if there are more than one of any type of product. In SQL, this would work something like:

```
SELECT Product FROM SOME_TABLE HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

I can't for the life of me work out how to do this in LINQ. I was following someone who did something like this:

```
    Dim q = From row In d.AsEnumerable()
            Group row By New { column1 = row("Product"), column2 = row("Value") }
            Into grp
            Where grp.Count() > 1
            Select row

    For Each item In q
        ' 'q' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
    Next
```

But I get an error when I try to actually use 'q'. Any ideas on how I can make this work?

Comment: This was what I was following:  http://www.thereforesystems.com/find-duplicates-using-linq/

Comment: You want to group on both Product and value? With your sample data that wont give you any duplicates.

Comment: You're right. I've edited the SQL query to reflect what I actually want. I want to find duplicate Product types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
Dim duplicates = d.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(Function(i) i.Field(Of String)("Product")).Where(Function(g) g.Count() > 1).Select(Function(g) g.Key)

For Each dup In duplicates
Next
```

Comment: Nice and simple solution. Thank.

Answer (score 1):

Just try

```
Dim q = From row in d.AsEnumerable()
        Group row By row.Field(Of String)("Product")
        Into grp
        Where grp.Count() > 1
        Select { Country = row("Product"), Value = row("Value") }
```

Comment: I tried that, and got the following error: Range variable name can be inferred only from a simple or qualified name with no arguments.

Comment: Try using the field extension method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about query syntax with VB.NET by try this

```
Dim q = d.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(r) New With { .Column1 = r("Product"), .Column2 = r("Value")}) _
                    .GroupBy(Function(r) New With {r.Column1, r.Column2}) _
                    .Where(Function(g) g.Count() >1 )

For Each item In q
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key)
Next
```